# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class Button

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have this exception when the app tries to launch the LoginActivity.

```
    ExceptionHandler: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Main.activity.LoginActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class Button
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Main.activity.LoginActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class Button
    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x1
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:737)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1451)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:113)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:61)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at Main.activity.LoginActivity_.setContentView(LoginActivity_.java:62)
    at Main.activity.LoginActivity_.0onCreate(LoginActivity_.java:44)
    at Main.activity.LoginActivity_.onCreate(LoginActivity_.java)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.ja
```

And here's the code to my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bleu_canard"
    tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_accueil"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/alo_login_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xxbig">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/alo_admin_grp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/alo_logo_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/alo_logo_image"
                android:text="Configurer site et groupe"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/alo_form_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alo_admin_grp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_big"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_xbig"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_xbig"
            tools:context=".LoginActivity">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alo_show_password_checkbox"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:theme="@style/BleuCanardButton" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/alo_login_edittext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
                android:hint="@string/login_txt_login"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/alo_password_edittext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alo_login_edittext"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
                android:hint="@string/login_txt_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alo_locked_account_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alo_password_edittext"
                android:text="@string/error_authentification"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/alo_show_password_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alo_locked_account_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/show_password"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/alo_pin_modification_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:text="@string/login_change_pin"
                android:theme="@style/BleuCanardButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/alo_password_modification_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/alo_pin_modification_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:text="@string/login_change_password"
                android:theme="@style/BleuCanardButton" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/alo_tech_info_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/alo_login_layout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alo_login_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alo_wrapping_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wrappe_no"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_smaller" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alo_environmet_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alo_wrapping_text"
            android:text="@string/mdm"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_smaller" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alo_site_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alo_environmet_text"
            android:text="@string/no_site"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_smaller" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alo_group_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alo_site_text"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/no_group"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_smaller" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alo_app_version_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alo_group_text"
            android:text="@string/app_version"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_smaller" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/alo_environment_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/alo_tech_info_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/alo_login_layout"
        android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <include
        layout="@layout/view_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The exception says that the problem comes from the line #95? which is the "hint" line down below.
I don't think that the problem comes from that line :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/alo_password_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/alo_validate_button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/alo_validate_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/alo_login_edittext"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
    **android:hint="@string/login_txt_password"**
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
```

I don't understand this part of the exception and the relation with inflating the button class :

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x1
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:737)
```

Here's my strings.xml file. All the strings called in the xml layout are present in the file.

```
<!-- Login Activity-->
<string name="development">DEV</string>
<string name="qualification">QUALIF</string>
<string name="recette">REC</string>
<string name="ti">TI</string>
<string name="integration">INTEG</string>
<string name="preprod">PPROD</string>
<string name="production">PROD</string>
<string name="formation">FOR</string>

<string name="wrappe_yes">WRAPPE : OUI</string>
<string name="wrappe_no">WRAPPE : NON</string>
<string name="mdm">MDM : </string>
<string name="set_mdm">MDM : %1$s</string>
<string name="no_site">SITE : Aucun</string>
<string name="set_site">SITE : %1$s</string>
<string name="no_group">GROUPE : Aucun</string>
<string name="set_group">GROUPE : %1$s</string>
<string name="app_version">APP : 0.0.0</string>
<string name="set_app_version">APP : %1$s</string>

<string name="login_txt_login">Identifiant</string>
<string name="login_txt_password">Mot de passe</string>
<string name="login_txt_fill_all_fields">Veuillez fournir votre identifiant et mot de passe.</string>
<string name="login_txt_version">Version %s</string>
<string name="error_authentification">Les informations de connexion sont incorrectes</string>
<string name="error_incorrect_password">Le mot de passe est erroné</string>
<string name="error_incorrect_login">Le nom d\'utilisateur n\'existe pas</string>
<string name="show_password">Afficher les caractères </string>
<string name="hide_password">Cacher les caractères </string>
<string name="login">CONNEXION</string>
<string name="lost_password">Mot de passe oublié ?</string>
<string name="user_does_not_exist">L\'utilisateur demandé n\'existe pas ou le mot de passe est incorrect</string>
<string name="user_locked">Compte bloqué. Vous pourrez réessayer dans %d secondes.</string>
<string name="login_change_password">MODIFIER SON MOT DE PASSE</string>
<string name="login_change_pin">CONNEXION AVEC REINITIALISATION DU PIN</string>
<string name="progress.login">Connexion en cours…</string>
```

dimens.xml :

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="header_height">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_title_width">180dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="default_button_height">60dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="button_big">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_height">80dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="margin_xxsmall">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_xsmall">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_small">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_medium">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_big">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_xbig">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_xxbig">80dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="text_xxsmaller">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_xsmaller">20sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="text_smaller">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_small">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_xsmall">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_medium">18sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_xmedium">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_big">24sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="custom_status_bar_height">24dp</dimen>
    <!-- Application dimensions TO CLEAN-->
    <dimen name="menu_text_size">25sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="menu_text_size_big">50sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="filter_pane_minWidth">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="filter_pane_Width">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="vcf_left">150dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="tv_documentsView_empty_minWith">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tv_documentsView_empty_minHeight">100dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="dialog_synchronization_minWidth">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dialog_download_report_minWidth">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tv_documents_synchronization_padding">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pbar_documents_synchronization_minWidth">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pbar_documets_synchronization_minHeight">25dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="lv_documents_synchronization_minHeight">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btn_application_padding">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btn_application_margin">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tv_separator_padding">6dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tv_spacingPadding">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pbar_spacingPadding">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tv_drawablePadding">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="row_synchronization_minHeight">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btn_synchronization_cancel_minWidth">200dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="question_size">28sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="layout_margin_medium">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="layout_margin_medium2">175dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="pdf_bookmark_drawer_width">400dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pdf_bookmark_row_height">50dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="ops_recycler_width_xsmall">260dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ops_recycler_width">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ops_recycler_width_big">450dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ops_recycler_width_small">360dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ops_recycler_height">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Only one user of the app has this problem

Comment: Post your string.xml and dimen.xml

Comment: @RujulGandhi I edited my post.

Comment: You have entered login into strings.xml twice

Comment: I only have one string called "login". Is the problem coming from the string called "progress.login" ?

Comment: yup replace it with "_"  instead of "."

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the problem comes from the naming of the strings. I don't understand why but "progress.login" is recognized as the same as "progress_login"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used `layout_alignStart` ,`layout_alignEnd` which are not supported below 16.

If your user is using device version below 16 than you have to replace it with `layout_alignLeft` ,`layout_alignRight`.

Comment: Will have to see with the user. But thank you so much for the leads. I will update the post as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: My minimum sdk version is 21

Comment: Okay Still you are facing this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem now.
This problem naturally has many reasons to occur.
Some of which are:

1. Using a too large resource.
2. Assigning a resource that has alternate files like: Landscape and Portrait, Night and Day.

The second was the issue I experienced, I set `?iconTint` on a ImageView that was declared in styles/day but not in styles/night. So, when I activated dark mode, it began giving the error.
For this question, take a look at here:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class Button
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x1
> The issue is on the Button
> Check the resources you are using on the button, and ensure they have values available for the different files you provide.